# Portal 2 Cross Platform Coop

Tags: portal-2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Play Portal 2 co-op between the PC and PS3 Steam linked accounts](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/20397/play-portal-2-co-op-between-the-pc-and-ps3-steam-linked-accounts)

I noticed in the game that when I had earned a flag, I have a notification that my coop team mates on Xbox and PS3 will not see my player customisations.

Does this mean that the game supports coop across platforms and if it does how do you find a coop team mate on an alternate platform?

Comment: Ahh, I didn't find that in my search.

Comment: This is not at all a duplicate question. This is asking about cross platform capabilities; the other asks only about PC and PS3 and makes no mention of XBox Live.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The PC and PS3 versions of the game can play with each other, and you can use the Steam friends list to set yourself up with a test associate.

Xbox 360 users get their own walled garden to play in and can't socialize with others.

Answer (score 0):

You associate your PSN with your Steam account and it allows you to access your Steam friends list from within the PS3 version. The PC version can also see you logged in on Steam and invite you to play a game. From there, it works just like playing on the PC.

If you get the PS3 version, you also get a code that allows you to download the PC/Mac version on Steam, just in case you want to play it there.

Comment: I'd point out that Microsoft's XBox Live system doesn't play nice with Steam. Because they XBox Live system is different than Valve's Steam system, with different friends, different accounts — and most importantly, *different servers* — users of XBox Live cannot interact *in any way* with users of Steam.