# Portal 2 Co-op with a single Steam account?

Tags: steam, portal-2

I picked up Portal 2 and wanted to try co-op with my son. We have two computers, but just one Steam account. Usually this is fine since I just leave the family computer in offline mode. Unfortunately it would appear that Portal 2 only does co-op when Steam is online.

Is there a way to do Portal 2 Co-op / multiplayer with a single Steam account on two PC's? I saw [you can with a PS3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/20397/play-portal-2-co-op-between-the-pc-and-ps3-steam-linked-accounts), and there is [no split screen on a single PC](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/22157).

Comment: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/20769/can-we-play-portal-2-co-op-on-one-pc-or-mac

Comment: @Badp Didn't know about the split screen, but Matthew Reed got me pointed in the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: I don't know if it was before, but split screen is available now.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

As it sounds like you're aware, you cannot be logged in to Steam in two separate locations at the same time (unless one or both are in offline mode, and thus unable to play online).

But, as badp notes, [another question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/20769/can-we-play-portal-2-co-op-on-one-pc-or-mac) talks about [a hack for single-PC splitscreen](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=1847904).

**Edit:** Suprisingly, [it looks like you can play with Steam offline over a LAN](http://forums.techarena.in/video-games/1404384.htm):

Go to "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\portal 2\portal2\scripts" or to the relevant folder or drive where you installed Portal 2. Now you have to add the following code in "extras.txt":

```
"lan"
{
    "title"     "Host LAN"
    "subtitle"  "sv_lan 1"
    "pic"       "vgui/extras/attract01"
    "command"   "sv_lan 1"
}

"lan"
{
    "title"     "Connect"
    "subtitle"  "192.168.1.1"
    "pic"       "vgui/extras/attract01"
    "command"   "connect 192.168.1.1"
}

"lobby"
{
    "title"     "Start Coop Lobby"
    "subtitle"  "Kind of pointless..."
    "pic"       "vgui/extras/attract01"
    "command"   "map mp_coop_lobby_2"
}
```

Select **Start LAN** on the host computer and select **Connect** on the computer. Then the host should select **Start**. Make sure the IP Address is correct for the HOST.

Alternatively you can use the console:

1. Enable the console via *Main Menu, then hit Options: Keyboard and Mouse: Enable Developer’s Console* **OR** add *-console* to the Portal 2 launch options.
2. Press ~ to toggle the console.
3. Run Portal 2 offline on both computers
4. On the HOST `sv_lan 1` in the console
5. On the other type `connect <host ip>` in the console
6. On the HOST type `map mp_coop_start` or any other MP map in the console

Comment: I'll be back to edit it some more next time we try playing it.

Comment: Are achievements able to be unlocked this way?

Comment: @John I would assume it works for Portal's in-game achievements, but I'd be doubtful as to whether it would sync with the Steam achievements.

Comment: Where do I select "Start Lan" or "Connect"? I can't find these options in the interface.

Comment: The extras.txt didn't work for me. The easiest was to just enable the console on both machines and follow the steps.

Comment: you don't have to hack to get single player splitscreen, its a built in option in the game!

Comment: oh, when you use the console to host a LAN game, does it save your level progress?