# Does Portal 2 coop require a consistent connection?

Tags: portal-2

I don't have a consistent connection and ping gets high on occasion. Can I still play Portal 2 coop, relying only on the saves in between levels or do I still have to be online 100% during the whole game?

Comment: How else are you going to be able to play with another person in real time?

Comment: Is there an option to use a LAN connection instead and just have both log on to the hub for the saving progress part?

Comment: That I don't know, someone else might be able to answer that for you.  I always had the impression that there is no LAN play at all.  I could be wrong.

Comment: You can play in LAN, just like every multi-player Steam game IMO

Comment: [You can play over a LAN](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/26884/6066) though I'm not sure if you can get achievements -- it requires being offline to use the same Steam account on both PCs, but I don't know what happens if you use different accounts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my experience, the co-op level stops and immediately kicks you both out of the game if one person disconnects.  I played on the Xbox 360 version, but I've been told the PC version exhibits the same behavior.

In my experience, there are generally at least one or two parts of each puzzle or puzzle sequence where timing is important.  The game even gives you a way to give your partner a countdown in order to synchronize your actions with the other person.  Trying to play on a very high latency or intermittent connection would likely be quite frustrating, but potentially doable if you're both patient.

Comment: It does, but high lag != disconnect. +1 anyways.

Comment: He mentioned that he doesn't have a consistent connection, which to me means it disconnects periodically.  However, it's possible that I misinterpreted.

Comment: Oh. Anyways, in my experience it gives you 25 seconds to reconnect.

Answer (score 4):

Levels are in general short and your progress are saved automatically after each completed one.

I suggest you to let your buddy host the game, if he/she has a more stable connection and in general I believe you can enjoy the co-op part of the game without major problems, even with your inconsistent connection.